# How can I validate the credentials(google service account json key) using GCP python sdk for storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-services, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I want to validate google service account credentials, which I have got from my google service account in the form of JSON key.

I tried validating the credentials by performing list buckets operation on the storage cloud and it was a success.

Now, I tried a negative scenario where I **removed** few of the keys from json file like:
**"type": "yy",
"private_key_id": "dsfdngdhgdsafa",
"client_id": "12133423123",**

But I am still able to access my bucket list giving no errors, but when I change any other keys other than shown above like:"private_key", then it fails.

Can anyone help me with, the explanation that this keys are not at all required or are for specific purpose ? why is this happening ? or any other way I can validate the credentials ?

Answer (score 2):

**[Update 2021-08-25]**

Google Cloud publishes the public certificate for a Google Cloud service account private key. After a service account private key is deleted or invalidated, the public certificate is removed preventing validation of data signed with the private key. The location of the certificate is located in the service account JSON. The two keys are **client_x509_cert_url** and **private_key_id**. The **private_key_id** is used to select the matching public certificate.

[Deep Dive into Google Cloud IAM Signblob and Service Accounts](https://www.jhanley.com/deep-dive-into-google-cloud-iam-signblob-and-service-accounts/)

**[End Update]**

The only items required are the Private Key `private_key` and the email address `client_email`. Everything else are `comments` for your usage (or the client libraries) or provide additional information for lookups on Google's end, for example: `private_key_id`.

I am not speaking for client libraries that may or may not implement their own common sense error checking. Study the libraries that you are using for details.

Google does not have/provide any security or validation of service account JSON key files. You are responsible for protecting the file and its contents.

You can use the service account, create a Signed JWT and call the Google Endpoint. An invalid JWT will return an error.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

I wrote an article that shows how to take a service account, create a Signed JWT and exchange for an OAuth Access Token. My article includes working Python source code. You could use my code as an example to create your own validation function.

[Creating OAuth Access Tokens for REST API Calls](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/)